# What is the cheapest way to get from Düsseldorf Weeze Airport (NRN) to Nijmegen (NL)

Tags: budget, germany, airport-transfer, netherlands, nrn

What is the cheapest way to get from Nijmegen Central Station to Düsseldorf Weeze Airport and, after a trip of several days, back from the same airport to Nijmegen Central Station?

I want to minimise the cost, but the journey shouldn't take more than 2 hours and I need to be certain that I arrive at the airport on time. This means hitchhiking is not an option.

I have found a [shuttle](http://www.airport-weeze-shuttle.de/haupthp/html/time-table.php) bus but it costs €18 for a single and €30 for a two-way ticket. I hope to find something cheaper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a bus from the Airport to Goch, then a train to Kleve (Niederrhein) and another bus to Nijmegen. Theticket from the Airport to Goch would cost 2,40 EUR
[image: bus timetable]

From Goch you can take a train to Kleve and then Bus SB58. One way ticket costs 10,50 EUR(VRR Tarif). DB-Bahn shows it costs 4,90 EUR, however I don't know if you have to pay extra for the part between Nijmegen and the Kranenburg (German Border). You can see the timetable on  [DB Bahn website](http://www.bahn.de/i/view/USA/en/index.shtml)
[image: vrr]

Comment: I'm not sure if the €4.90 fee is only for the train part or for the full journey including the two busses. It does say `partial fare` and one needs to call a taxi bus 30 minutes in advance. As a taxi bus is involved it might mean that extra costs are also present.

Comment: @BartArondson I updatet my answer